# gdebi: installing deb package with python < 3.7 dependency

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, deb

I need to install the Phillips Pathology SDK, which is distributed as a collection of modules that depend on Python 3.6. They can currently be downloaded from [this link](https://philips.mizecx.com/knowledgeDocument.html?8c9fb46d2da926d4d89043d5014feab8). This comes with an install bash script that installs all the modules. The script goes like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
PYTHON3_VERSION="py3"
ACCEPT=$2
INPUT_PYTHON_VERSION=$1

if [ "$INPUT_PYTHON_VERSION" = "" ];then
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)Python argument Not given$(tput sgr 0)"
        exit
fi

agreement() {
echo "$(tput setaf 3)By installing this software, you agree to the End User License Agreement for Research Use.$(tput sgr 0)"
echo "$(tput setaf 3)Type 'y' to accept.$(tput sgr 0)"
read -p "Enter your response:"  ACCEPT_AGREEMENT
}

installSdk() {
apt-get install -y gdebi
if [ "$PYTHON3_VERSION" = "$INPUT_PYTHON_VERSION" ];then
        echo "$(tput setaf 2)Installing PathologySDK2.0 modules please wait... $(tput sgr 0)"
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-modules/*pixelengine*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-pixelengine*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-modules/*eglrendercontext*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-eglrendercontext*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-modules/*gles2renderbackend*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-gles2renderbackend*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-modules/*gles3renderbackend*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-gles3renderbackend*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-modules/*softwarerenderer*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-softwarerenderbackend*.deb
        gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-softwarerendercontext*.deb
        echo "$(tput setaf 2)PathologySDK2.0 successfully installed$(tput sgr 0)"

else
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)Selected python version is NOT supported.$(tput sgr 0)"
        exit 0

fi

}

if [ "$ACCEPT" = "-y" ]; then
    echo "$(tput setaf 2)Accepted end user license agreement.$(tput sgr 0)"
    installSdk
    exit 0
elif [ "$ACCEPT" = "" ];then
    agreement
    if [ "$ACCEPT_AGREEMENT" = "y" ]; then
        installSdk
        exit 0
    else
        echo "$(tput setaf 1)Exiting installation. Please accept the end user license agreement to install the SDK.$(tput sgr 0)"
        exit 0
    fi
else
    echo "$(tput setaf 1)Exiting installation. Please accept the end user license agreement to install the SDK.$(tput sgr 0)"
    exit 0
fi
```

I use miniconda to manage Python environments and created a new python=3.6.3 environment to install these modules. However, when it runs the second command (gdebi -n ./pathologysdk-python36-modules/*python3-pixelengine*.deb), it fails with the following error:

```
This package is uninstallable 
Dependency is not satisfiable: python3 (< 3.7)
```

If I run `python3 --version`, I get "Python 3.6.3". If I run the gdebi command myself without the script in the environment, I get the same error.

How can I make gdebi use the Python version of my conda envinroment?

Comment: what is your os version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, I'm using their 18.04 installer

Comment: If anybody is interested from the future: I ended up dockerizing the analysis because I could not make it work with a conda environment alone.